# graphics scrolling with c#

Tags: c#, scroll, graphics

Using Visual Studio C# we are trying to draw fairly simple graphics (polygons) in a panel. I can get scrolling to work in a textbox by turning on the scrolling but if it is just graphics lines in a panel, then setting AutoScroll=true does not seem to have any effect even if the graphics extend past the dimensions of the panel. What else needs to be enabled to set to make this work?

I see a number of other settings like "AutoScrollMinSize". So far attempting to pick non-zero values for all of these seems not to help.

Comment: A `Panel` doesn't know anything about the graphics you're drawing on it, so it won't automatically show scrollbars when you're trying to draw outside its bounds or draw the graphics further to one side or the other based on the position of a scroll bar.  That said, you can implement scrolling fairly easily yourself by providing a scrollbar with the appropriate values and using the [Graphics.Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform(v=vs.110).aspx) matrix.

Comment: @adv12 Nailed it.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Assuming Winforms: AutoScrollMinSize is the way to go. Make it as large as you want the virtual canvas to be, turn on AutoScroll. Done. Adding scrollbars yourself is a bad and tedious idea!

Comment: Ultimately, it is waveforms that are to be shown. I did try this once with a seperately created scroll bar but I could not get it to scroll very nicely.

Comment: This is a windows application, I had thought that was implied by the forum but apparently not. This is the first time using this forum. I just tried it with the AutoScrollMinSize set to the size of the panel and it mostly works! It Scrolls but leaves the old image so the lines become very wide bars. So the next think it to find a way to clean that up.

Comment: Does one have to add code to erase the old graphic lines before adding new ones? if so, since the old ones are scrolled up or down, how does one find their position to erase them?

Comment: Solved with -panel1.VerticalScroll.Value